# Remove duplicates only if all the fields have same data

Tags: c#, if-statement, duplicates, code-first

I have a requirement to remove the duplicates only if all my fields have same data in an XML.But the problem here is it is not a List and my field names are also different.
for ex:

```
Scenario:1

<Items>-->Not a List just an generic object Type T
<Name1A>test1</Name1A>
<Book1A>booktest1</Book1A>
<Page1A>pagetest1<Page2A>
<Name2A>test2</Name2A>
<Book2A>booktest2</Book2A>
<Page2A>pagetest2</Page2A>
</Items>
```

In this case I have to populate all the above fields

```
Scenario 2:
<Items>-->Not a List just an generic object Type T
<Name1A>test1</Name1A>
<Book1A>booktest1</Book1A>
<Page1A>pagetest1<Page2A>
<Name2A>test1</Name2A>
<Book2A>booktest1</Book2A>
<Page2A>pagetest1</Page2A>
</Items>
```

In this case I have to populate only `<Name1A>,<Book1A>,<Page1A>` because in the next set of fields my data is same.

```
Scenario 3:
<Items>-->Not a List just an generic object Type T
<Name1A>test1</Name1A>
<Book1A>booktest1</Book1A>
<Page1A>pagetest1<Page2A>
<Name2A>test2</Name2A>
<Book2A>booktest1</Book2A>
<Page2A>pagetest1</Page2A>
</Items>
```

In this case also I would expect to populate all the fields because `<Name2A>`data is different.

Comment: Can you slap the person who designed this XML? Also, what have you tried? Parsing an XML and keeping a count is pretty trivial, so you can look up elements `"Name" + number + "A"`.

Comment: Hi CodeCaster- Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am trying to convert this to list and use distinct to remove the duplicates.Thanks for your suggestion.I will try it.

Comment: I mean it's easier for others to help you if you show some code, even if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a class to represent your items:

```
class Item {

  public Item(String name, String book, String page) {
    Name = name;
    Book = book;
    Page = page;
  }

  public String Name { get; }

  public String Book { get; }

  public String Page { get; }

}
```

Your XML is quite bizare and you need to write a small parser. Transforming an input sequence (`XElement`) into another sequence (`Item`) can be done using an iterator block:

```
IEnumerable<Item> ParseXml(XElement root) {
  var elements = root.Elements().ToList();
  if (elements.Count%3 != 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("Number of XML child elements is not divisible by 3.");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.Count/3; i += 1) {
    var nameElement = elements[3*i];
    ThrowIfUnexpectedElement(nameElement, "Name", i + 1);
    var bookElement = elements[3*i + 1];
    ThrowIfUnexpectedElement(bookElement, "Book", i + 1);
    var pageElement = elements[3*i + 2];
    ThrowIfUnexpectedElement(pageElement, "Page", i + 1);
    yield return new Item(
      (String) nameElement,
      (String) bookElement,
      (String) pageElement
    );
  }
}

void ThrowIfUnexpectedElement(XElement element, String prefix, Int32 index) {
  var expectedName = $"{prefix}{index}A";
  if (element.Name.LocalName != expectedName)
    throw new ArgumentException($"Unexpected XML element '{element.Name.LocalName}'. Expected '{expectedName}'.");
}
```

Now you can parse the XML:

```
var items = ParseXml(xDocument.Root);
```

To remove duplicates you can use `Distinct()` combined with an `IEqualityComparer<Item>`:

```
class ItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item> {

  public Boolean Equals(Item item1, Item item2) {
    return item1.Name == item2.Name
      && item1.Book == item2.Book
      && item1.Page == item2.Page;
  }

  public Int32 GetHashCode(Item item) {
    unchecked {
      const Int32 Multiplier = -1521134295;
      var hash = -175858345;
      hash = hash*Multiplier + item.Name.GetHashCode();
      hash = hash*Multiplier + item.Book.GetHashCode();
      hash = hash*Multiplier + item.Page.GetHashCode();
      return hash;
    }
  }

}
```

You get the distinct items using this code:

```
var distinctItems = items.Distinct(new ItemEqualityComparer());
```